# How to right align a slide out panel for all screen sizes?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am trying to right align the panel so it works with bootstrap, and so it works for all screen sizes. The left align works for all screen sizes. How can I make this work for the right align?

[FIDDLE](http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/puj9r/5/)

Javascript

```
 $('#opener').on('click', function() {                          
                                var panel = $('#slide-panel');
                                if (panel.hasClass("visible")) {
                                                panel.removeClass('visible').animate({'margin-left':'100%'});
                                } else {
                                                panel.addClass('visible').animate({'margin-left':'90%'});
                                }             
                                return false;      
                });
```

CSS

```
#slide-panel {
    width:300px;
    height:300px;
    padding:10px;
    background:#eee;
    margin-left:100%;
}
#opener {
    float:left;
    margin:-10px -50px 0px -50px;
    border-radius:0;
}
```

HTML

```
<div id="slide-panel">
    <a href="#" class="btn btn-danger" id="opener"><i class="glyphicon glyphicon-align-justify"></i></a>
    Panel Content
</div>
```

Comment: Are you able to make the side panel be `position: fixed` or `position: absolute`?

Comment: If you can: http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/ZnNHk/

Comment: the horizontal scroller shows up .. when u scroll horizontally u can see the panel before its even opened

Comment: you can set body to 100% width and overflow:none. That fixes it

Comment: Try that too didnt seem to work http://jsfiddle.net/dev1212/puj9r/19/

Comment: I think @Gisheri meant `overflow: hidden`. See my updated Fiddle. I assumed you want to still scroll vertically, so I did `overflow-x: hidden`

Answer (score 1):

Making a side panel can be done with the following steps:

- Make the panel `position: absolute` or `position: fixed`
- Make the panel be `top: 0` and `right: -N` where N is the width of the panel
- To show the panel set `right` to `0`
- To make it so there isn't a scrollbar, set `overflow-x: hidden` on the body and html

This only works if the width of the side panel is constant.

Here's the Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/acbabis/ZnNHk/